# Join column and using group by with having too slow

Tags: mysql, laravel

I has 3 tables: Customer, Bill, Bill_service. 
Table Customer has 30k rows. 
Table Bill has 200k rows. 
I want to get list customer who has bill latest between range date 
Here is my code:

```
$customer = Customer::select('customer.id', 'customer.name')
    ->join('bill', 'bill.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
    ->groupBy('customer.id', 'customer.name')
    ->havingRaw('MAX(bill.date)', '>=', '2020-07-01')
    ->havingRaw('MAX(bill.date)', '<=', '2020-07-31')
    ->paginate(20)
```

It's take 10s to execute above query. Is there any others way to do this case? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your query? I guess sum operation costed a lot

Comment: @Spikie I have just edited my question. Each customer has a lot of bills. I want to get list customer go to my shop buy service on latest date between range date

Comment: you used MAX function on date column, so even if you have index on it, it wil use full scan for each user!

Comment: @Spikie I know but there is no other way to get list of customers with the above condition. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be interesting to see the raw query and and EXPLAIN of it, but it all looks very straightforward so I don't see much hope of something being wrong that you could easily fix, assuming you have sensible indexes (indexes for bill.customer_id and bill_service.bill_id).

The only suggestion I would have is to avoid the customer table entirely and just group by bill.customer_id, and look up the customer names for the rows after pagination (I don't know if laravel provides a way to join after pagination or if that would need to be a separate query.)

Update: the question was significantly changed.  It appears to me it could benefit from adding a where condition for bill.date >= '2020-07-01' and a composite `(customer_id, bill_date)` index on the bill table.  But before doing that, get the raw query (using ->toSql()) and run EXPLAIN on it.  From comments, it seems like you are in fact missing critical indexes.

Comment: You know clearly my problem. Let's me try :))

Comment: you've changed your question!  now it looks like it might benefit from some changes and a composite index on bill date and customer_id

Comment: I realized that add index to customer_id make select query run much faster. But does it make insert or update query slower?

Comment: marginally slower at worst